# Is it possible to read the health check state out of Traefik?

Tags: traefik

Is it possible to read out or receive webhook events when the health state of a backend changes?

We would like to post the events to an emergency slack channel so that we can remediate the situation whenever a backend is unhealthy. We could set a different monitoring solution, such as Rancher's health checks or Grafana alerts. It seems it would be less trouble and more reliable to obtain our operations alert from our Traefik instance directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not feasible right now to my knowledge.

The closest you can get to is to use a metrics system like Prometheus and set up a proper alert for too many failing health checks.